# how can I print the names of the devices found?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

this is the code for searching for bluetooth devices

```
private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
private Set dispositivi;

...

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        ...
        btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        ...
    }

private void load()
    {
        dispositivi = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        Log.d("type", dispositivi.getClass().getName());
        adapter.clear();
        for(Object bt : dispositivi)
            adapter.add(bt.toString());   <-- here print 1F:8H:0F:54:2A:55,
    }
```

how can i print the name of device?

Answer (score 0):

```
private Set<BluetoothDevice> dispositivi;
```

it was enough to modify the set